# UINavigationController crash UI on swipe action (black screen, video inside)

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIViewController` which is pushed from `navigationController`  that uses custom left/back button with interactivePopGestureRecognizer, however, when I click a row from tableview my app sometimes stucks and after pressing home button and going background then reopening the app, it continues but swipe action of navigationcontroller becomes weird. Here is the video of what am I saying;

https://streamable.com/xvl38

```
//This is the function that I use to open chat from tableview on didSelectRowAt

func openChat(with nick: String, isFromConversationList: Bool) {
        guard let chatVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: .main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChatViewController") as? ChatViewController,
            let rootNC = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController else {
                return
        }
        rootNC.pushViewController(chatVC, animated: true)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = nil
}
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)   
    self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = true
}
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false

}
```

What can be the reason for that?

Comment: I realized that console throws an error when this ui problem occurs. " 2018-02-05 13:58:17.864489+0300 ABC[315:29648] Got memory pressure notification (non-critical)
2018-02-05 13:58:45.524810+0300 ABC[315:29648] System is no longer under (non-critical) memory pressure."

Comment: You are using custom transition ? , if yes then check `yourViewController.view.snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates` returning nil value if you have use this method

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya No I am not using custom transition. I have edited code and added viewController push code. There is no extra transition. The snapshot is not returning nil value, I can see my ViewController clearly.

Comment: Any link to a sample project you can provide?

Comment: could you try removing `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` ? Then in `viewDidLoad` set `view.backgroundColor = .red` for current view controller and set it to a different colour for the previous view controller. Just to try and understand what is happening.

Comment: @BerkKaya, May i know, why are you trying to set root instead of push.

Comment: @user1046037 This is not happening everytime, interactivePopGestureRecognizer is the what causes the problem. I can't remove it, if I do there is no way to crash that navigationcontroller.

Comment: @InderJagdeo Am I setting root? I don't think so. I'm just getting current root and pushing to the Chat

Comment: I don't set `interactivePopGestureRecognizer`, I just use `pushViewController` and pop is automatically detected when the user swipes back or presses the back button. So I was wondering if it was really necessary.

Comment: @BerkKaya How did you set custom back button? Why are you getting NC from window's rootViewController property? Are that NC and viewController's NC the same instance? Could please share detailed code snippet or gist? It would be much easier to understand what is happening.

Comment: Undeterministic `UIKit` behavior is often indication of some change happening not on the main thread.

Comment: Why do you make the delegate nil? If it works but when you end the app and rereturn to it this happen, then you may need to use `deinit` and reset the delegate to the old one.